# Capturing Groups From a Grep RegEx

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I've got this script in `sh` (macOS 10.6) to look through an array of files:

```
files="*.jpg"
for f in $files
    do
        echo $f | grep -oEi '[0-9]+_([a-z]+)_[0-9a-z]*'
        name=$?
        echo $name
    done
```

So far `$name` merely holds 0, 1 or 2, depending on if `grep` found that the filename matched the matter provided. What I'd like is to capture what's inside the parens `([a-z]+)` and store that to a variable.

I'd like to use `grep` only, if possible. If not, please no Python or Perl, etc. `sed` or something like it – I would like to attack this from the *nix purist angle.

Comment: Ah, didn't mean to suggest that. I was just hoping that a solution could be found using a tool I'm specifically trying to learn here. If it's not possible to solve using `grep`, then `sed` would be great, if it's possible to solve using `sed`.

Comment: I should have put a :) on that btw ...

Comment: Psh, my brain is way too fried today haha.

Comment: @martinclayton That'd be an interesting argument.
I do really think sed, (or ed to be precise) would be older (and therefore purer? maybe?) unix because grep derives it's name from the ed expression g(lobal)/re(gular expression)/p(rint).

Answer (score 690, accepted):

If you're using Bash, you don't even have to use `grep`:

```
files="*.jpg"
regex="[0-9]+_([a-z]+)_[0-9a-z]*" # put the regex in a variable because some patterns won't work if included literally
for f in $files    # unquoted in order to allow the glob to expand
do
    if [[ $f =~ $regex ]]
    then
        name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        echo "${name}.jpg"    # concatenate strings
        name="${name}.jpg"    # same thing stored in a variable
    else
        echo "$f doesn't match" >&2 # this could get noisy if there are a lot of non-matching files
    fi
done
```

**It's better to put the regex in a variable. Some patterns won't work if included literally.**

This uses  `=~` which is Bash's regex match operator. The results of the match are saved to an array called `$BASH_REMATCH`. The first capture group is stored in index 1, the second (if any) in index 2, etc. Index zero is the full match.

---

---

---

side note #1 regarding regex anchors:

You should be aware that without anchors, this regex (and the one using `grep`) will match any of the following examples and more, which may not be what you're looking for:

```
123_abc_d4e5
xyz123_abc_d4e5
123_abc_d4e5.xyz
xyz123_abc_d4e5.xyz
```

To eliminate the second and fourth examples, make your regex like this:

```
^[0-9]+_([a-z]+)_[0-9a-z]*
```

which says the string must *start* with one or more digits. The carat represents the beginning of the string. If you add a dollar sign at the end of the regex, like this:

```
^[0-9]+_([a-z]+)_[0-9a-z]*$
```

then the third example will also be eliminated since the dot is not among the characters in the regex and the dollar sign represents the end of the string. Note that the fourth example fails this match as well.

side note #2 regarding `grep` and the `\K` operator:

If you have GNU `grep` (around 2.5 or later, I think, when the `\K` operator was added):

```
name=$(echo "$f" | grep -Po '(?i)[0-9]+_\K[a-z]+(?=_[0-9a-z]*)').jpg
```

The `\K` operator (variable-length look-behind) causes the preceding pattern to match, but doesn't include the match in the result. The fixed-length equivalent is `(?<=)` - the pattern would be included before the closing parenthesis. You must use `\K` if quantifiers may match strings of different lengths (e.g. `+`, `*`, `{2,4}`).

The `(?=)` operator matches fixed or variable-length patterns and is called "look-ahead". It also does not include the matched string in the result.

In order to make the match case-insensitive, the `(?i)` operator is used. It affects the patterns that follow it so its position is significant.

The regex might need to be adjusted depending on whether there are other characters in the filename. You'll note that in this case, I show an example of concatenating a string at the same time that the substring is captured.

Comment: In this answer I want to upvote the specific line that says "It's better to put the regex in a variable. Some patterns won't work if included literally."

Comment: "It's better to put the regex in a variable. Some patterns won't work if included literally." - Why does it happens? Is there a way fix them?

Comment: @FrancescoFrassinelli: An example is a pattern that includes white space. It's awkward to escape and you can't use quotes since that forces it from a regex to an ordinary string. The correct way to do it is to use a variable. Quotes can be used during the assignment making things much simpler.

Comment: However, Bash regex doesn't support lazy matching.

Comment: \K operator is a lifesaver, when all you wanted was a quick one-liner for your directory operation. (my specific case was look for a name in a file, and make some directories as a result). so `grep -P -o "blah \K([stuffhere]+)" somefile | godosomethingwiththat`

Comment: This simply doesn't work. No regex matches regardless of the regex or input string

Comment: @Brandon: It does work. What version of Bash are you using? Show me what you're doing that doesn't work and perhaps I can tell you why.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson `4.3.11(1)-release`. I literally copied the example verbatim. `echo "${name}.jpg"` echos ".jpg"

Comment: @Brandon: Do you have files in the current directory that match the pattern? For example, `touch 012_abc_03a.jpg 345_def_14b.jpg` would create a couple of empty test files that the regex matches. In my answer, the regex match and its output should be part of an `if` statement instead of standing alone in order to avoid outputting empty results. I'll make that change in order to improve clarity.

Comment: I'm not using files, I've adapted it to my scenario which is a svn log to retrieve text from a commit. I have the regex, it matches using grep but it doesn't match with =~.

Comment: @Brandon: Without a specific example, I can't be of any help. Perhaps you should post the issue as its own question.

Comment: @Brandon It does work and the example is easy enough to understand. In fact, it's a great answer. You're definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: question was about GREP, not BASH

Comment: @mdelolmo: My answer includes information about `grep`. It was also accepted by the OP and upvoted quite a lot. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @WylliamJudd You almost certainly have a typo. Which command does it say isn't found? What version of Bash?

Comment: Fore example `regex="([A-z]+)\."` `"foo.bar"=~$regex` `-bash: foo.bar=~([A-z]+)\.: command not found`

Comment: @WylliamJudd: There needs to be spaces around the `=~` and that expression needs to be within double brackets. In brace expansions such as in your second message it's not necessary to escape characters (the dot is always literal - that's a glob, not a regex).

Comment: I did it both ways. `"foo.bar" =~ $regex` still gives `-bash: foo.bar: command not found`. `[["foo.bar" =~ $regex]]` also gives `-bash: [[foo.bar: command not found`

Thanks for the tip on the superfluous escape.

Comment: @WylliamJudd You _also_ need spaces inside the double brackets just as I show in my answer.

Comment: Ah! I thought those double braces were the equivalent of parentheses for an if statement, and since I have no if statement in my use case, I didn't realize I needed them. Thanks! :)

Comment: The part with grep and `\K` operator is great when you are using sh, not bash, for example in a buildroot package makefile.

Comment: In such case, the BASH_REMATCH fails with `*** missing separator.` and you don't really know why, until you realize the buildsystem might be using sh.

Answer (score 190):

This isn't really possible with pure `grep`, at least not generally.

But if your pattern is suitable, you may be able to use `grep` multiple times within a pipeline to first reduce your line to a known format, and then to extract just the bit you want. (Although tools like `cut` and `sed` are far better at this).

Suppose for the sake of argument that your pattern was a bit simpler: `[0-9]+_([a-z]+)_` You could extract this like so:

```
echo $name | grep -Ei '[0-9]+_[a-z]+_' | grep -oEi '[a-z]+'
```

The first `grep` would remove any lines that didn't match your overall patern, the second `grep` (which has `--only-matching` specified) would display the alpha portion of the name. This only works because the pattern is suitable: "alpha portion" is specific enough to pull out what you want.

(Aside: Personally I'd use `grep` + `cut` to achieve what you are after: `echo $name | grep {pattern} | cut -d _ -f 2`. This gets `cut` to parse the line into fields by splitting on the delimiter `_`, and returns just field 2 (field numbers start at 1)).

Unix philosophy is to have tools which do one thing, and do it well, and combine them to achieve non-trivial tasks, so I'd argue that `grep` + `sed` etc is a more Unixy way of doing things :-)

Comment: `for f in $files; do name=`echo $f | grep -oEi '[0-9]+_([a-z]+)_[0-9a-z]*'| cut -d _ -f 2`;` Aha!

Comment: i disagree with that "philosophy". if you can use the shell's in built capabilities without calling external commands, then your script will be a lot faster in performance. there are some tools that overlap in function. eg grep and sed and awk. all of them does string manipulations, but awk stands out above them all because it can do a lot more. Practically, all those chaining of commands, like the above double greps or grep+sed can be shortened by doing them with one awk process.

Comment: @ghostdog74: No argument here that chaining lots of tiny operations together is generally less efficient than doing it all in one place, but I stand by my assertion that the Unix philosophy is lots of tools working together. For instance, tar just archives files, it doesn't compress them, and because it outputs to STDOUT by default you can pipe it across the network with netcat, or compress it with bzip2, etc. Which to my mind reinforces the convention and general ethos that Unix tools should be able to work together in pipes.

Comment: cut is awesome -- thanks for the tip! As for the tools vs efficiency argument, I like the simplicity of chaining tools.

Comment: props for grep's o option, that is very helpful

Answer (score 126):

I realize that an answer was already accepted for this, but from a "strictly *nix purist angle" it seems like the right tool for the job is **`pcregrep`**, which doesn't seem to have been mentioned yet.  Try changing the lines:

```
    echo $f | grep -oEi '[0-9]+_([a-z]+)_[0-9a-z]*'
    name=$?
```

to the following:

```
    name=$(echo $f | pcregrep -o1 -Ei '[0-9]+_([a-z]+)_[0-9a-z]*')
```

to get only the contents of the capturing group 1.

The **`pcregrep`** tool utilizes all of the same syntax you've already used with **`grep`**, but implements the functionality that you need.

The parameter **`-o`** works just like the `grep` version if it is bare, but it also accepts a numeric parameter in `pcregrep`, which indicates which capturing group you want to show.

With this solution there is a bare minimum of change required in the script.  You simply replace one modular utility with another and tweak the parameters.

**Interesting Note:** You can use multiple -o arguments to return multiple capture groups in the order in which they appear on the line.

Comment: `pcregrep` is not available by default in `Mac OS X` which is what the OP uses

Comment: My `pcregrep` doesn't seem to understand the digit after the `-o`: "Unknown option letter '1' in "-o1". Also no mention of that functionaliy when looking at `pcregrep --help`

Comment: i can't reproduce it. probably the impl of this `pcregrep` is different. could you provide more info? what about the difference between this and `grep -P`? not even in man page:  http://linux.die.net/man/1/pcregrep

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg What version are you using? I have the same issue and found reference to it [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/536243).

Comment: @WAF sorry, guess I should have included that info in my comment. I'm on Centos 6.5 and the pcregrep version is apparently very old: `7.8 2008-09-05`.

Comment: yeah, very help, e.g. `echo 'r123456 foo 2016-03-17' | pcregrep -o1 'r([0-9]+)'
123456
`

Comment: On macOS, `brew install pcre`. Also note that Homebrew's zsh depends on pcre, so you may already have pcre if you installed that.

Comment: `pcregrep` 8.41 (installed with `apt-get install pcregrep` on `Ubuntu 16.03`) doesn't recognize the `-Ei` switch. It works perfectly without it, though.

On macOS, with `pcregrep` installed via `homebrew` (also 8.41) as @anishpatel mentions above, at least on High Sierra the `-E` switch is also not recognized.

Comment: Another handy option is `--om-separator=text` (only matching separator) which specifies a separating string. For example, `--om-separator=", "` separates matches by commas

Answer (score 43):

Not possible in just grep I believe

for sed:

```
name=`echo $f | sed -E 's/([0-9]+_([a-z]+)_[0-9a-z]*)|.*/\2/'`
```

I'll take a stab at the bonus though:

```
echo "$name.jpg"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that `sed` solution doesn't work. It simply prints out everything in my directory.

Comment: updated, will output a blank line if there isn't a match, so be sure to check for that

Comment: It now outputs only blank lines!

Comment: this sed has a problem. The first group of capturing parenthesis encompass everything. Of course \2 will have nothing.

Comment: it worked for some simple test cases... \2 gets the inner group

Comment: NAILED THE "BONUS" ;)

Answer (score 25):

```
str="1w 2d 1h"
regex="([0-9])w ([0-9])d ([0-9])h"
if [[ $str =~ $regex ]]
then
    week="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    day="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    hour="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    echo $week --- $day ---- $hour
fi
```

output:
1 --- 2 ---- 1

Answer (score 21):

This is a solution that uses gawk. It's something I find I need to use often so I created a function for it

```
function regex1 { gawk 'match($0,/'$1'/, ary) {print ary['${2:-'1'}']}'; }
```

to use just do

```
$ echo 'hello world' | regex1 'hello\s(.*)'
world
```

Comment: Great idea, but does not seem to work with spaces in the regexp - they need to be replaced with `\s`. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @opsb What is the purpose of - `ary['${2:-'1'}']}'`? Couldn't we have done the same thing with - `function regex1 { gawk 'match($0,/'$1'/, ary) {print ary[1]}'; }` to match the 1st occurrence?

Edit: Never mind! got the intention.

Answer (score 6):

A suggestion for you - you can use parameter expansion to remove the part of the name from the last underscore onwards, and similarly at the start:

```
f=001_abc_0za.jpg
work=${f%_*}
name=${work#*_}
```

Then `name` will have the value `abc`.

See Apple [developer docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html), search forward for 'Parameter Expansion'.

Comment: this will not check for ([a-z]+).

Comment: @levislevis - that's true, but, as commented by the OP, it does do what was needed.

Answer (score 4):

if you have bash, you can use extended globbing

```
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s nocaseglob
for file in +([0-9])_+([a-z])_+([a-z0-9]).jpg
do
   IFS="_"
   set -- $file
   echo "This is your captured output : $2"
done
```

or

```
ls +([0-9])_+([a-z])_+([a-z0-9]).jpg | while read file
do
   IFS="_"
   set -- $file
   echo "This is your captured output : $2"
done
```

Comment: That looks intriguing. Could you perhaps append a little explanation to it? Or, if you're so inclined, link to a particularly insightful resource that explains it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the one line `python` or `perl` command, both often included in major linux disdribution

```sh
echo $'
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">
</a>
<a href="http://google.com">
</a>
' |  python -c $'
import re
import sys
for i in sys.stdin:
  g=re.match(r\'.*href="(.*)"\',i);
  if g is not None:
    print g.group(1)
'
```

and to handle files:

```sh
ls *.txt | python -c $'
import sys
import re
for i in sys.stdin:
  i=i.strip()
  f=open(i,"r")
  for j in f:
    g=re.match(r\'.*href="(.*)"\',j);
    if g is not None:
      print g.group(1)
  f.close()
'
```

Comment: +1 for the multiline python program, I feel like this is a fairly standard way of doing this on a lot of systems, that's also inline yet much more flexible than standard bash tools.

Comment: Ever try doing this in Vim or Neovim? A well-used list comprehension makes it possible to populate your script with batched sh command lines.

Answer (score 4):

The follow example shows how to extract the 3 character sequence from a filename using a regex capture group:

```sh
for f in 123_abc_123.jpg 123_xyz_432.jpg
do
    echo "f:    " $f
    name=$( perl -ne 'if (/[0-9]+_([a-z]+)_[0-9a-z]*/) { print $1 . "\n" }' <<< $f )
    echo "name: " $name
done
```

Outputs:

```
f:     123_abc_123.jpg
name:  abc
f:     123_xyz_432.jpg
name:  xyz
```

So the if-regex conditional in `perl` will filter out all non-matching lines at the same time, for those lines that do match, it will apply the capture group(s) which you can access with `$1`, `$2`, ... respectively,

Comment: I wish I would have found this a week ago. Works great, thanks!!!