# Grepping for the form action= part of html pages

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I am trying to grep the parts of an html form, specifically the action part i.e. `<form action = ….`
I originally tried:
`grep -E -e 'form\s*action\s*=.*[.]html' ./*`
but it did not work (despite the fact that there are such strings.
Then I tried the basic:  `grep -E -e 'form\s*action\s*=' ./*` but this did not work either!
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For the `./*` part, you mean current directory? And what is the error message?

Comment: So you want to match the content of the action or you want only `<form action = ….` ? and in your first expression what is the `xs` at the end for ?

Comment: `xs` is a file. Like html

Comment: @nl-x Don't escape the backslash, it's only for grep and well protected with single quotes. Else it will match a backslash followed with a 's'.

Answer (score 1):

This wont get you the action. It will get you the part just before the action. For example if you have `<form id="myForm" action="myFile.php">`the regexp will just get you `form id="myForm" action=`

So try in stead:

`grep -E -o -i -e '<form\s+[^>]*action\s*=[^>]*>' ./*`

`[^>]*` means everything except `>`, zero or more times.
`-o` means only get the matching part
`-i` means case insensitive

Comment: Even this `grep -E -e 'form\\s*action\\s*=' ./*` does not give any results or `grep -E -e '\<form\\s*action\\s*=.*\>' ./*` does not work either

Comment: @Jim I was wrong about double escaping. I edited my answer. I tested it, and it works

Comment: `grep -E -e '<form\s*[^>]*action\\s*=[^>]*>' ./*` does not work either

Comment: It needs `-r`! Your test was in the current directory probably!

Comment: I would add a `\b` after `form`, or replace the first `\s*` with `\s+`, else you can match `<formaction=...>`. Maybe it's unnecessary... Else, works fine for me too, +1.

Comment: @Jim -r is recursive. You didn't mention you wanted to go recursive. My test was on a single file

Comment: @Bentoy13 Tnx. It was indeed supposed to be \s+ ... I'll edit it

Comment: All I couldn't manage yet is to only return the contents of the action attribute. I can only return the entire regexp match. I tried making a group with parenthesis `(...)` , but GREP just ignores that... Maybe I should name the group, or add some extra switch

Comment: @nl-x I think that you can achieve returning only the action part using lookbehind and adding option `-P` for that. It's up to you!

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1891890/1209443 I can use Grep multiple times by piping it. I can see how that would work...

Comment: @nl-x Yeah, with grep, only way to do that because you cannot specify variable-length pattern into lookbehind. So yes, pipe seems to be the only way!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a html parser/xpath implementation? Like my [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

This returns the url in the action part:

```
xidel ./* -e //form/@action
```

Or with pattern matching, instead xpath:

```
xidel ./* -e '<form action="{.}"/>*'
```

You can even do all further processing in it. E.g. to not only get the action, but also the values of all input-elements url-encoded you can use:

```
xidel ./* -e //form/form(.)
```