# Pass the matched value to a function, and replace with the return value

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

How would I get Bash to match a regular expression, but rather than replace the value with a constant string, it will instead pass the matched value to a function, and then get the value to replace with from the return value of the function.

Something like the following pseudocode, which replaces every match of `[a-d]` with the same character, but uppercase:

```
function uppercase() { echo ${1^^}; }
string="abcdefgh123cbazyz"
echo ${string//[a-d]/uppercase()}
# output: ABCDef123CBAzyz
```

I'm not particular, any language that is typically installed on a Unix system (such as `sed`, `awk`, or even the limited regex support built into `bash`) can be used.

Comment: If I want the match to be global, it is not so simple as re-running the function several times, as the return value may contain values which in turn are matched by the regular expression.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891797/capturing-groups-from-a-grep-regex

Answer (score 4):

Bash can't use user defined functions inside [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

To accomplish what you want, use [pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) with case modification:

```
string="abcdefgh123cbazyz"
echo ${string^^[a-d]}
```

Output:

```
ABCDefgh123CBAzyz
```

Comment: Wow, +1, impressive tiny geeky feature of Bash, not so well documented...?! :)

Comment: Documentation: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion and http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching

Answer (score 1):

You can use Perl for this:

```
perl -lape 's/([a-d])/`uppercase $1`/eg' <<< "$string"
```

but this will require an **executable** script named `uppercase`. Perl `e` (eval) flag executed a command on the match when there is a match.

Another way via sed:

```
function uppercase() { 
    echo ${1^^} 
}
export -f uppercase
string="abcdefgh123cbazyz"
echo "echo $(sed 's/\([a-d]\)/$(uppercase \1)/g' <<< "$string")" | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `tr`:

```
echo abcdefgh123cbazyz | tr '[a-d]' '[A-D]'
```

Or `sed`:

```
echo abcdefgh123cbazyz | sed -r 's|[a-d]|\U&|g'
```

Output:

```
ABCDefgh123CBAzyz
```

#### Update

Callback with `Ruby`:

```
puts "abcdefgh123cbazyz".gsub(/[a-d]/){ |m| m.upcase }
```

Callbak with `Python`:

```
import re

s = "abcdefgh123cbazyz"

def repl(m):
    return m.upper()

print(re.sub('\[\[:(.+?):\]\]', repl, s))
```

Callback with `Perl`:

```
my $s = "abcdefgh123cbazyz";
$s =~ s/([a-d])/uc($1)/eg;
print "${s}\n";
```

Output:

```
ABCDefgh123CBAzyz
```

Comment: Can either of those point to a bash function instead? (changing characters to uppercase was just one limited use case)

Comment: IQAndreas It's not possible with Bash. Perhaps it could work with other languages where callbacks are possible.

Comment: @IQAndreas See update for Python and Ruby callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl you can capture the group and pass it to a subroutine like this, using the `e` flag:

```
perl -pe 'sub callback { return uc $_[0] } s/([a-d])/callback $1/eg' <<<"$string"
```

Output for your string:

```
ABCDefgh123CBAzyz
```

Here I've just provided my own wrapper around the existing  function [`uc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/uc.html) that returns converts letters to uppercase. You can change the body of the subroutine to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW here's how you'd do it in GNU awk (for the 4th arg to split()):

```
$ cat tst.awk                                                
function uppercase(str) { return toupper(str) }
{
    split($0,flds,/[a-d]/,seps)
    for (i=1;i in flds; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", flds[i], uppercase(seps[i])
    }
    print ""
}

$ echo "abcdefgh123cbazyz" | gawk -f tst.awk
ABCDefgh123CBAzyz
```

or with any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk                                                
function uppercase(str) { return toupper(str) }
{
    while ( match($0,/[a-d]/) ) {
        printf "%s%s", substr($0,1,RSTART-1), uppercase(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH))
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}

$ echo "abcdefgh123cbazyz" | awk -f tst.awk
ABCDefgh123CBAzyz
```