# Combine regex patterns to match groups inside delimited strings

Tags: regex, sed, substring, grouping

## Background

Looking to replace periods with dollar signs only within text that is delimited by dollar signs (never spanning lines). For example:

```
Names: $annie.bettie.cindy.dannie.ellie$. Only $a$ names. $a.b.c.d.e.f$.
```

## Problem

The [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/bX7FKR/2) almost works, but is too simple:

```
/([[:alnum:]])\.([[:alnum:]])/g
```

If a match exists outside of the delimiters (`$`), then too much will be replaced.

The following regex:

```
/\$.*?\$/g
```

[Matches and groups](https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/187) the delimited strings:

> Names: **$annie.bettie.cindy.dannie.ellie$**. Only **$a$** names. **$a.b.c.d.e.f$**.

## Question

How do I combine the two regular expressions so that the periods can be replaced with another string? For example:

```
Names: $annie.bettie.cindy.dannie.ellie$. Only $a$ names. $a.b.c.d.e.f$.
```

Ultimately will become:

```
Names: `r v$annie$bettie$cindy$dannie$ellie`. Only `r v$a` names. `r v$a$b$c$d$e$f`.
```

The trouble I'm having is matching the delimited dots.

The regular expression will be piped into sed from a terminal running bash.

Comment: Maybe [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241413/pass-the-matched-value-to-a-function-and-replace-with-the-return-value) can throw some light.

Comment: can you explain your expected output? problem statement said you need to replace `.` with `$` within `$sometext$` pattern.. particularly I don't get the ```r v``` part as well as the missing `$` at end of pattern

Comment: @Sundeep: The goal is to create a regex that converts simple [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) YAML variable references to the more powerful inline [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/^(([^$]*\$[^$.]*\$)*[^$]*\$[^$.]*)\./\1\n/;ta;s/(\$[^$]*)\$/`r v\1`/g;y/\n/$/' file
```

Replace all periods within the groups by a newlines. Insert groups prefix and suffix literals and then translate the newlines to dollars.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
Names: $annie.bettie.cindy.dannie.ellie$. Only $a$ names. $a.b.c.d.e.f$.

$ perl -pe '
BEGIN
{
    sub f
    {
        $a = $_[0] =~ tr/./$/r;
        $a =~ s/^/`r v/;
        $a =~ s/.$/`/;
        return $a;
    }
}
s/\$.*?\$/f($&)/ge
' ip.txt
Names: `r v$annie$bettie$cindy$dannie$ellie`. Only `r v$a` names. `r v$a$b$c$d$e$f`.
```

- The subroutine `f` performs the necessary transformation for `$sometext$` strings - first transliterate `.` to `$`, then add some string to beginning and finally remove last character to replace with required format

  - The subroutine is put in a `BEGIN` block, which is executed before processing the input file line by line
- `s/\$.*?\$/f($&)/ge` will extract the `$sometext$` pattern and pass on to `f` subroutine. Perl knows to call it courtesy the `e` flag
- `-p` switch means input line gets printed after all commands