# Rename batch of specific files using bash

Tags: macos, bash, file, rename

Say I have a folder which contains files like this: a constant prefix and then an underscore and some description which is different for every file:

```
constantnamehere_description1.doc
constantnamehere_description2.doc
.
.
etc
```

Here description1, description2 etc just symbolized the different descriptions and not the actual number 1,2 etc..

How can I rename these files to just this?

```
constantnamehere1.doc
constantnamehere2.doc
.
.
etc
```

Here the numbers 1,2,..,etc symbolize the actual sequential ending that i want my files to have after the renaming.
The sequential ending (1,2,3,...,end) is very important.

Till now I have tried:

```
for i in *.doc; do mv "$i" "{i/_*.doc/ .doc}"; done
```

example actual file names

```
1003407_cc_1.vtk
1003407_cc_2.vtk
1003407_cc_3.vtk
1003407_cv.left.right.vtk
1003407_thalamo_frontal.left.vtk
```

I want to be like:

```
1003407_1.vtk
1003407_2.vtk
1003407_3.vtk
1003407_4.vtk
1003407_5.vtk
```

To make it extremely clear: I want everything to be removed after the first underscore and to be replaced with sequential numbers keeping the ".vtk" extension of the file

Comment: Does the order of the files matter?

Comment: yes. It would be preferred to stay unchanged

Comment: But your question states that there is no such order at the beginning because the numbers are actually just placeholders for different desriptions. So how can it remain unchanged? :) I meant, does it matter which file is number 1, number 2 and so on?

Comment: The way you put it no. I just meant that i want the operation every time to give the same "random" result concerning the numbering. Because i will perform it to a lot of folders which contain the same files, so after the operation, i want the correspondence to still apply

Comment: Ok, in that case you should be fine with my solution posted below because Bash will  replace the `*` "with an alphabetically sorted list of file names matching the pattern" (from `bash(1)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
i=0; 
for file in *.vtk; do mv "${file}" 100307_"${i}".vtk; i=$((i+1)); done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the an answer to [Capturing Groups From a Grep RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1892107/1983854), we can generate a regex for these file names and then rename by using the captured groups:

```
$ regex="([^_]*)_[^0-9]*([0-9]*).([a-z]*)"
$ for f in *doc
do 
    [[ $f =~ $regex ]]
    echo "mv $f --> ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
done
```

The regex says: get everything up to `_`, then expect some characters until a digit is found. Catch that set of digits and then expect a dot followed by the extension.

Comment: i'll give it a try and i ll get back at you

Comment: it works fine but it doesn't put the number 1,2,3 etc at the end of constantnamehere

Comment: @gelazari You are right, I didn't notice this before. Just completely rewrote the answer.

Comment: check now my edit at the bottom with actual file names

Comment: @gelazari So now, after all the attempts we've been doing, you come up with some different approach: apparently, your input files do not have a number in there, whereas you did state that in the initial question. Make your mind clear and indicate what you want, because I am not going to update my answer anytime you come up with a different idea.

Comment: some of them do have a number at the end but some don't. Thats why i posted actual names.

Comment: @gelazari You should have said that beforehand. It is tiring to keep updating the answer and I am not going to do it anymore.

Comment: In simple terms I want everything to be removed after the first underscore and to be replaced with sequential numbers keeping the ".vtk" extension of the file

Comment: @gelazari check the first version of the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28857893/1 It should be trivial to get your desired output from that version, you just need to add the counter.

Comment: @MichaelJaros i voted you up guys but i solved it with my way. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `rename`:

```
i=1
for file in *_*.vtk
do 
  rename "s/_[^.]*/${i}/" "$file"
  i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

This removes everything between the underscore and the first `.` from all files matching the `*_*.vtk` pattern. If your filenames contain more than one `.`, the pattern needs to be adapted.

EDIT: Solution modified according to modified question.

Comment: how can it be modified to add also 1,2,3,etc at the end of the name?

Comment: I've just added the numbering. Now I have used some Bash too in addition to `rename`. It's still not too complex.

Comment: It looks quite risky to add the numbers sequentially, not very sure if this matches the OP requests

Comment: check now my edit at the bottom with actual file names

Comment: @gelazari: Is it important to preserve the number in the variable part of the filename if there is any?

Comment: @fedorqui: I may have assumed too much, but if I read the comments on the question, this looks like what the OP wants to me. Maybe after my last question we will know.

Comment: no. I just want them to have sequential numbers after the constantPrefix but of course, if i perform the same operation in different folders containing the same set of files, i want them to rename all the files exactly with the same way every time.

Comment: Ok, then the sequential numbering in my code should meet your requirements. Bash performs wildcard (e.g. `*`) expansion alphabetically, so the result should be always the same with the same set of files.

Comment: @MichaelJaros is there any different way using mv instead of rename? I want to perform the operation also on a macintosh

Comment: @gelazari: Sure there is, but it needs a different approach and I wish you had given me this little information before letting me modify the `rename` approach 10 times :( Unfortunately I have to attend to something else now, but I'm sure some of the other members can help. I'll suggest to retag for Mac, maybe that helps.