# regular expression with grep not working?

Tags: regex, grep, udp, cygwin

I am running cygwin, grep 2.21 on Windows 7.
I am trying to get all tcp connections from netstat, so I run the following:

```
netstat | grep -i "^(TCP|UDP)"
```

Now, it returns nothing, but when I run `netstat` it clearly returns a bunch of tcp connections.  I also tried :

```
netstat | egrep -i "^(TCP|UDP)"
```

Also returns nothing. What am I missing here?  I thought that the caret means "begins with".  Thanks.

Comment: The caret matches the position before the first character in a string.  Is TCP or UDP the first part of a string (is there any whitespace before it)?

Comment: My guess is it's something to do with netstat being a dynamic utility - there's no output available to pipe into grep. Even if you do `netstat | grep "80"` it doesn't work.

Comment: @remus What do you mean by "dynamic utility"? If it displays output on the terminal, that same output should go into the pipe.

Comment: It should work with `egrep`. It doesn't work with `grep` because `|` is not part of Basic Regular Expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[netstat](/questions/tagged/netstat) outputs the protocol using lower case characters. Try either of the following:

```
netstat | grep '^\(udp\|tcp\)'
```

or

```
netstat | egrep '^(udp|tcp)'
```

The difference between the two is that [egrep](/questions/tagged/egrep) supports an extended regular expression syntax in which `(`, `)` and `|` should not be escaped. As [Reuel Ramos Ribeiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2561091) noted, 
`egrep` is equivalent to using `grep -e` so alternatively one could use `netstat | grep -e '^(udp|tcp)'`.

Answer (score 2):

For me, `netstat | grep -P '(tcp|udp)'` worked.

You may want to use the `i` flag to ignore the case if necessary.

```
netstat | grep -Pi '(TcP|UDp)'
```

About the other answer here, using `egrep` or `grep -e` gives the same result. Based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17949/what-is-the-difference-between-grep-egrep-and-fgrep).

The `-P` flag was inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891797/capturing-groups-from-a-grep-regex).

Using the option `-P`, accordingly to `man grep`, sets the pattern interpreter as [perl](/questions/tagged/perl). Not sure why it did not work without `-P` though.

Comment: Good answer, the `-e` comment should have been a comment to my post rather than being included in your answer though.

Comment: I still have not enough reputation to comment on other answers :/

Comment: Oh, sorry, should have noticed that. Well at least you got ten points from my upvote. Keep up the good work and you'll have the reputation soon. Try to also markup your posts so they are readable and understandable, this will only improve the quality of your posts. More information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).