# Does exist more convenient manner to get the svn revision number output from svn log?

Tags: shell, svn, grep

please see below :

```
echo "r22543 | foobar | 2016-03-08 17:17:02 +0800  | 1 line" | egrep -o 'r[0-9]+' | egrep -o '[0-9]+'
22543
```

Does exist more convenient manner to get the svn revision number?

Answer (score 0):

could use pcregrep, see below

```
 echo 'r123456 foo 2016-03-17' | pcregrep -o1 'r([0-9]+)'
 123456
```

I see it from [Capturing Groups From a Grep RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891797/capturing-groups-from-a-grep-regex)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`--xml` command line option](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.xml) and parse the xml'ed output instead of grepping.

`svn log https://svn.example.com/myrepo --xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
<logentry
   revision="123">
<author>MyAuthor</author>
<date>2016-03-16T14:05:26.310474Z</date>
<msg>Created folder 'foo'.</msg>
</logentry>
</log>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite easily done with good old `sed`:

```
echo "r22543 | foobar | 2016-03-08 17:17:02 +0800  | 1 line" | sed 's/^r\([^[:space:]]\+\).*/\1/'
```