# How to verify the output of a command in shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to verify if a particular file system has the *noexec* option set.

For example `/dev/shm`. I am running the command in the following manner:

```
get_val=$(mount|grep /dev/shm )
if [[ -z get_val ]] ; then
   # Error
else
   value=$(echo "${get_val}" | cut -d " " -f 6 | grep noexec)
   if [ "${value}" = "" ]; then
     # Not set
   else
     # Set
    fi
fi
```

The value of get_val is something like `devshm on /dev/shm type devshm (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)`

Next what I want to do is check if `gid` and `mode` has been set to a certain value. However, with the above procedure, I can only check if an option is set.

So I tried this:

```
echo "${get_val}"| cut -d " " -f 6 | awk -F, '{
if ($4 == "gid=123"){
print 1;
}
else
{ print 0;}
if ($5 == "mode=123)"){
print 1;
}
else
{ print 0;}'
```

However, this seems too hassle-ish and I am not sure what will be the better way to do this.

Also other parameters could be set in a filesystem such as nodev etc which would make $5 or $2 different.

any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891797/capturing-groups-from-a-grep-regex

Comment: You can finish this with multiple greps IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you really should be turning to Awk even for the basic processing.

```
if mount | awk '$1 == "/dev/shm" && $6 ~ /(^|,)noexec(,|$)/ &&
    $6 ~ /(^|,)gid=123(,|$)/ && $6 ~ /(^|,)mode=123(,|$)/ { exit 0 }
  END { exit 1 }'
then
    echo fine
else
    echo fail
fi
```

The `(^|,)` and `(,|$)` anchors are to make sure the matches are bracketed either by commas or beginning/end of field, to avoid partial matches (like `mode=1234`).

Getting Awk to set its return code so it can be used idiomatically in an `if` condition is a little bit of a hassle, but a good general idea to learn.

Comment: `/dev/shm` might not be the first argument output in the line, as you can see in the sample output i have provided

Comment: Right - convert to a regex then, or examine `$3` instead of `$1` if it's always the third field.

Answer (score 0):

Why not directly use globbing with `[[`:

```
[[ ${get_val} == *\(*gid=5*\)* ]] && echo 'Matched'
```

Similarly, with "mode=0620":

```
[[ ${get_val} == *\(*mode=0620*\)* ]] && echo 'Matched'
```

If you prefer Regex way:

```
[[ ${get_val} =~ \(.*gid=5.*\) ]] && echo 'Matched'
[[ ${get_val} =~ \(.*mode=0620.*\) ]] && echo 'Matched'
```

Comment: There is a catch here: If the mountpoint path contains `gid=5` (say `/tmp/gid=5` or stupid `/dev/shm-who-uses-such-weird-names-gid=5`) these regex will match & give wrong results. So, we should match substring of `$get_val`, to match only the options part of the result...

Comment: No, now this will return `Matched`, even if there is no match in the line. e.g. try with `get_val='devshm on /dev/shm type devshm (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5)'` `[[ ${get_val} == *(*mode=0620*)* ]] && echo 'Matched'`

Comment: @anishsane Good catch, thanks. Forgot about the `extglob`-ing. Check now.

Comment: `get_val='devshm on /dev/shm type devshm (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5)' [[ ${get_val} == *\(*gid=58*\)* ]] && echo 'Matched'` also matches

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is stupid, but isn't it as simple as

```
mount | grep -E '^/dev/shm.*noexec' && value=1
((value)) && #Do something useful
```

If you wist to check multiple fields you can pipe the grep like below :

```
mount | grep -E '^/dev/shm.*noexec' \
| grep -E 'gid=5.*mode=0620|mode=0620.*gid=5' >/dev/null && value=1

((value==1)) && #Do something useful
```

Comment: It answers the beginning of the question, but if you read the rest, it looks like maybe the OP actually wants to validate these other fields as well

Comment: @tripleee : Why not use multiple greps as I have shown in the edit?

Comment: Multiple greps are an antipattern. You seem to be reaching for Awk, too.