# Not able to extract with grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

```
> <img alt="Citizen Kane Poster" title="Citizen Kane Poster"
src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ2Mjc1MDQwMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzUyOTUyMg@@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg"
itemprop="image" />
```

I want to extract the url of the poster from the above text.
This is my grep statement:

```
count=$(grep -zPo '(?<=> <img alt=").*?src="\K.*?(?="itemprop="image")'  ~/movie_local)
```

movie_local was where I had saved the page source of the site.
I am learning grep and haven't got a complete command over it,so please do go soft on me.Could you please help me out? :)

Comment: First off, [don't use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4060711). What you're looking for though, is a [capturing group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891797/capturing-groups-from-a-grep-regex).

Comment: I will look into it,thank you :) but is there no way I can do this using grep?Even with the extended perl regex is it not possible? I have done this on multiple occasions,but for this chunk of code it isn't working

Comment: A capturing group is a way to extract part of a match. I'm not familiar with how to use them in grep as command line is a little weird. That second link seems to explain it quite well though.

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Comment: Try `(?s)(?<=>\s*<img alt=").*?src="\K.*?(?="\s*itemprop="image")`

Comment: Can you explain the terms? I am really sorry,I am a newbie. Why do we use ?s and \s* ?

Comment: `(?s)` is the ["dotall" option](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcresyntax.html#SEC16) that makes `.` match `\n` too (which is the main problem with your regex); @WiktorStribiżew's comment provided the crucial pointer, but his regex uses a _variable-length_ lookbehind assertion, which isn't supported (at least as of GNU `grep` v2.26) - however, you don't need one at all, since you're already using `\K`. Wiktor added the `\s*` simply to make whitespace matching more flexible.

Comment: @3ocene: `grep` implementations (at least none I'm aware of) do not support capture groups: while you can use `(...)` for _grouping_, you won't be able to access what those groups _captured_. However, combining the `-o` option (return only the (entire) captured part) with lookaround assertions (requires GNU `grep` with `-P`) is a (limited) substitute for true capture-group support. It's exactly what this question's command attempts, but fails (for different reasons).

Comment: Actually, I added the `\s*` "manually" after testing. It won't work with the * quantifier. Anyway, yes, it is just a hint aand not an attempt to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As has been said many times before, the best solution is to use an HTML parser.)

With *GNU* `grep`, try this simplified version:

```
grep -zPo '<img alt=[^/]+?src="\K[^"]+' ~/movie_local
```

A fixed version of your original attempt (note the `(?s)` prefix; see below for an explanation):

```
grep -zPo '(?s)> <img alt=".*?src="\K.*?(?=")' ~/movie_local
```

Alternative, with `[\s\S]` used ad-hoc to match *any* char., including `\n`:

```
grep -zPo '> <img alt="[\s\S]*?src="\K.*?(?=")' ~/movie_local
```

---

As for **why your attempt didn't work**:

- **When you use `-P`** (for [PCRE (Perl-Compatible Regular Expression](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcre.html) support), **`.` does *not* match `\n` chars. *by default***, so even though you're using `-z` to read the entire input at once, `.*` won't match across line boundaries. You have two choices:

  - Set [**option `s`** ("dotall")](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcresyntax.html#SEC16) at the start of the regex - **`(?s)`** - this makes `.` match *any* character, including `\n`
  - Ad-hoc workaround: **use `[\s\S]`** instead of `.`
- As an aside: the **`\K` construct is a syntactically simpler and *sometimes* more flexible *alternative* to a lookbehind assertion (`(?<=...)`**.

  - Your command had *both*, which did no harm in this case, but was unnecessary.
  - By contrast, had you tried `(?<=>\s*<img alt=")` for more flexible whitespace matching - note the `\s*` in place of the original single space - your lookbehind assertion would have *failed*, because lookbehind assertions must be of *fixed length* (at least as of GNU `grep` v2.26).
    However, using just `\K` would have worked: `>\s*<img alt=")\K`.
    `\K` simply removes everything matched *so far* (doesn't include it in the output).