# Get specific key value in log pattern using the shell script

Tags: linux, shell

My log file has below pattern :-

```
 tx=267c5660-c49a-4ae7-b5ae-c9d43e23b617, rh=163.172.0.0, userId=-1, requestComplete={ requestId=74421156932, entityResourceType=xyz, pageId=homePage, uri=/home/, duration(ms)=422
```

How can i grep for just a specific field like `uri` or `duration` or combination of both like `uri` and `duration`.

Basically when i use tail command,I want in the o/p just 2 fields **uri and duration**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use cut command. According to logs there is one seperator i.e. ",". So we can use "," as a delimeter and we need to give field number, In our case it is 8,9 for uri and duration.

```
cat "logfile" | cut -d"," -f7,8
```

Thanks

Comment: UUOC. Skip the `cat` and the pipe and just append the filename to `cut` command

Answer (score 0):

For a variable like

```
var=$'2017-04-21 09:04:42,649 +0000 [exec-12056] EventLogger - cid=rio, tx=267c5660-c49a-4ae7-b5ae-c9d43e23b617, rh=163.172.0.0, userId=-1, requestComplete={ requestId=74421156932, entityResourceType=xyz, pageId=homePage, uri=/riokc95758/, duration(ms)=422'
```

You might consider something like this with GNU grep:

```
$ grep -Po 'uri=\K.[^,]*' <<<"$var"
/riokc95758/

$ grep -Po 'uri=/\K.[^,/]*' <<<"$var"
riokc95758

$ grep -Po '.*duration\(ms\)=\K.[^,]*' <<<"$var"  #if duration is the last field you can use just grep -Po '.*duration\(ms\)=\K.*'
422
```

Or even you can use sed with regex groups and backreferences :

```
$ sed -E "s/(.*uri=)(.[^,]*)(.*duration\(ms\)=)(.[^,]*)(.*)/\2,\4/" <<<"$var" 
/riokc95758/,422
```

You can assign each of above commands to a variable like `$ newvar=$(egrep .... )`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cut` if the pattern had a consistent number of comma-separated values. The order would have to be consistent as well.

Otherwise, a *double grep* can get the values you're looking for :

```
grep -Eo "uri=/.*/" | grep -Eo "/.*/" # gets uri
grep -Eo "duration\(ms\)=[0-9]+" | grep -Eo "[0-9]+" # gets duration
```

## Explanation :

In the first example  `grep -Eo "uri=/.*/"` on your input will return `duration(ms)=422`. Chaining it with a second grep allows you to isolate `422` alone.

This is somewhat similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1891890/639725)