# Bash script for getting tag value

Tags: xml, bash, shell

Is there any way to get value(Yes or No) if i only have tag("answer_yes" or "answer_no") which are described in a xml file. I want to get them using bash.

```
<string tag="answer_yes" value="Yes"/>
<string tag="answer_no" value="No"/>
```

Comment: BTW -- I assume there's a larger XML file that this is taken from? These two lines aren't a valid document as given, because they're not under a single root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an XML-aware tool. For this simple query, `xmllint` is enough:

```
answer=answer_yes
xmllint --xpath "//string[@tag='$answer']/@value" file.xml | cut -f2 -d\"
```

It seems not to expand entities, though, so if your real strings contain quotes, you'll have to replace `&quot;`, `&amp;`, and `&lt;` by `"`, `&`, and `<`, respectively.

[xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) handles the entities for you:

```
xsh -aC 'open file.xml; $answer={$ARGV[0]};
         echo //string[@tag=$answer]/@value' "$answer"
```

Answer (score 2):

To extract the `value` element of all strings with either `tag="answer_yes"` or `tag="answer_no"` in an XML document, [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) is an appropriate tool:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//string[@tag="answer_yes" or @tag="answer_no"]' -v '@value' -n
```

This will work in situations where naive regex-based approaches won't: It will recognize comments and CDATA as such and avoid trying to parse them; it will ignore `answer_` content that isn't inside a `string` or a `tag`; it will recognize aliases brought in through your DTD; it will properly change `&amp;` to `&` in output; it's agnostic to whether the `tag` or the `value` is given first in the element; it doesn't care about whether the whitespace separating the element from its attributes is tabs/spaces/newlines/etc; and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

In `sed` if your Input_file is same as shown sample then following may help you in same.

```
sed 's/.*answer_//;s/".*//'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
regex='tag="answer_yes"[[:space:]]+value="([^"]+)"'

if [[ '<string tag="answer_yes" value="Yes"/>' =~ $regex ]] ; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" ;
fi
```

Feel free to expand on the regex for more accurate matching.

Sources:

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns?highlight=%28regex%29
- [Capturing Groups From a Grep RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891797/capturing-groups-from-a-grep-regex)

Comment: Please don't link TLDP's documentation -- half of what we do in the Freenode #bash channel is helping people unlearn bad practices they picked up there.

Comment: (The bigger objection to this is that a regex can't understand XML syntax -- it won't ignore your `string` if it's in a comment; it won't understand that things inside `CDATA` sections are literal; it doesn't understand that an `xmlns="http://example.com/"` declaration makes something `{example.com}string` instead of `string`, etc).

Comment: (...back on documentation -- the [Wooledge BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) was written, and is actively maintained, to be a more accuracy- and best-practices-focused alternative).

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize. Thanks for pointing me towards a better bash guide!