# Grep - how to output only the content of a capturing group

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am trying to find a way for grep to output only the content of a capturing group. For instance, if I have the following file:

```
hello1, please match me
hello2, please do not match me
```

I would like

```sh
grep -Eo '(hello[0-9]+), please match me' file
```

To output `hello1`. However it outputs `hello1, please match me`.

Now, I know that `grep -Po 'hello[0-9]+(?=, please match me)'` will do the trick, but I'm thinking there must be a way to simply return a capturing group, but I couldn't find any info (on the net and in `man grep`).

Is it possible, or are capturing groups only meant to be backrefenced ? It would seem weird to me if there was no way of doing that.

Thank you for your time, and feel free to critique the way this post is constructed!

Comment: as far as I know, `GNU grep` doesn't support getting only the captured groups, unless you use lookarounds with PCRE option... `ripgrep` (an alternate implementation) does support what you are asking, but in spirit that is more like the search and replacement functionality provided by `sed`... so, if you need to manipulate capture groups, `sed` would be better choice

Comment: The non-consuming `(?=)` group with `-P` allows a sort of AND function in regexes.   The other way to AND your regexes with grep is to pipe grep to grep.   So what's wrong with piping grep to grep here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have either `pcregrep` or `pcre2grep` you can use the `-o1` command-line flag to request that only capture group 1 is output. (Or change 1 to some other number if there are more captures in the regex.)

You can use the `-oN` command more than once if you want to output more than one capture group.

As far as I know, `grep -P` does not implement this extension. You'll find `pcre2grep` in Debian/Ubuntu package `pcre2-utils`. `pcregrep` is in package `pcregrep`.

Comment: Why doesn't `apt` find PCRE2 as `pcre2grep` on Ubuntu 19.04? `$ sudo apt-get install pcre2grep; Reading package lists... Done; Building dependency tree; Reading state information... Done; E: Unable to locate package pcre2grep`

Comment: @vstepaniuk: As I said above, "You'll find pcre2grep in Debian/Ubuntu package **pcre2-utils**."

Comment: **Why** doesn't apt find PCRE2 as pcre2grep on Ubuntu 19.04?

Comment: @vstepaniuk: because whoever built the package which contains various utilities using libpcre2 chose not to build a separate package only containing pcre2grep. I have no idea what went into that decision. You would have to ask them. But `apt` only knows about package names.

Comment: "You can use the -oN command more than once if you want to output more than one capture group.". 
Which pcregrep supports this? I have pcregrep version 8.21 2011-12-12. When specifying multiple groups, only the last one gets returned.

echo 'Name:"John" Email:"john@example.com"' | pcregrep -o1 '(?=Name:"(\w+?)".*Email:"(\w+@\w+\.\w+)")'
John

echo 'Name:"John" Email:"john@example.com"' | pcregrep -o2 '(?=Name:"(\w+?)".*Email:"(\w+@\w+\.\w+)")'
john@example.com

 echo 'Name:"John" Email:"john@example.com"' | pcregrep -o1 -o2 '(?=Name:"(\w+?)".*Email:"(\w+@\w+\.\w+)")'
john@example.com

Comment: @zongjun: I have pcregrep v8.39 and pcre2grep v10.31, and both of them produce `Johnjohn@example.com` for your last command.

Comment: @rici, thanks for confirming. Version does matter. I aligned with your versions and can see your result now. Do you know is there a way to put a seperator between -o1 and -o2, say tab or space?  So result can be "John john@example.com"?

Comment: @Zongjun: `-om-separator=' '`. If you installed those programs, you should also have manpages installed, so you can get complete documentation by type `man pcregrep` or `man pcre2grep`. I just found that option by reading through the manpage.

Answer (score 60):

This question was asked [ten years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1891797/4375327), so I won't mark it as duplicate. Also I noticed no sed solution was given since OP asked an answer without:

```
sed -nr 's/(hello[0-9]+), please match me/\1/p' test.txt
```

- **`-n`** stands for quiet (won't print anything except if explicitly asked)
- **`-r`** allows use of extented regular expressions (avoids here using `\` before parenthesis)
- **`s/reg/repl/p`** command means "if regexp `reg` matches the current line, replace it by captured text by `repl`, and prints it (`/p`)"

Comment: It comes now full circle, since `g/re/p` means "globally search a regular expression and print"

Comment: @Amessihel, I'll chose Rici's answer because it is the closest to what i asked. Your answer is relly good too though, thank you.

Answer (score 42):

You can use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), which generally seems to be superior to grep, like this

```
rg '(hello[0-9]+), please match me' -or '$1' <file>
```

where ripgrep uses `-o` or `--only matching` and `-r` or `--replace` to output only the first capture group with `$1` (quoted to be avoid intepretation as a variable by the shell).

Comment: Beware of a bug if you combine `--replace` with `--multiline` in the currently released versions (v13.0.0 is the latest stable version at the time of writing). The output can contain (partially) duplicated results. The code has already been fixed, but no update has been released: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/2438#issuecomment-1451111793

Answer (score 6):

`grep`, `sed` and `awk` have ancient regular expression engines that don't support any modern regex features. I don't really think they're fit for purpose anymore.

One thing `Perl` is still good for is as a replacement for those in pretty much all one-liners, as it has a very nice, modern regex engine, and a couple of handy command line switches, `-ne` and `-pe`.

The switches cause Perl to automatically apply your expression to each line of the input and either unconditionally print the result, or let you control printing of the result.

For instance, to print the first `hello` followed by a digit (`hello\d`) for all lines that have `hello\d` followed by `please match me`, you can do:

```
perl -ne 'm/(hello\d) please match me/ && print "$1\n"' <file>
```

There are many nice sites out there that list common tasks you can do with a Perl one-liner, such as [this one](https://catonmat.net/perl-one-liners-explained-part-one).

I also think that [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) should be in everyone's toolbox.

Answer (score 5):

Just an `awk` version.

```
awk -F, '/hello[0-9]+, please match me/ {print $1}' file
hello1
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to use this— I don't see a capturing group in your regex.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson It output everything before the , if it has hello with a number and please match me.   You can use  `awk -F, '/, please match me/ {print $1}' file` to get anything in front of "please match me"

Answer (score 1):

There is a tricky way with Perl mode

```
$ echo "hello1, please match me" | rev | grep -oP 'em hctam esaelp ,\K[0-9]olleh' | rev
hello1
```

essentially using `\K` lookbehind by reversing the input and search terms.

You can outsource reversing the search term to `rev` as well.

```
$ echo hello1, please match me | 
  rev | 
  grep -oP "$(echo hello1K\\, please match me | rev)" | 
  rev
```

Comment: What's the benefit of this solution since OP asked of a simple way to return a captured group?

Comment: @Amessihel This doesn't really meet my requirement, sure, but I do find that this is a really funny solution

Comment: looking back is easier than looking ahead, most likely that's why there is a `\K` but not one for lookahead.  Not really for practical use...