# RegEx : Nested Groups and Quantifiers

Tags: regex, grep, grouping, quantifiers

This is my string : file_1234_test.pdf
Task is to find the filename-without-extension and find the number.
So the result should be :

```
> Match 1 = file_1234_test.pdf
> Group 1 = file_1234_test
> Group 2 = 1234
```

I found [Stack-58379142](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58379142/grep-how-to-output-only-the-content-of-a-capturing-group) but it does not answer my question.

I tested the following queries on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester)

Step 1. as expected

```
> (.*)\.pdf
> Match 1 = file_1234_test.pdf
> Group 1 = file_1234_test
```

Step 2. as expected : greedy '+' quantifier

```
> (\d+)
> Match 1 = 1234
> Group 1 = 1234
```

Step 3. still as expected

```
> ((\d+).*)
> Match 1 = 1234_test.pdf
> Group 1 = 1234_test.pdf
> Group 2 = 1234
```

Step 4. once again as expected

```
> ((\d+).*)\.pdf
> Match 1 = 1234_test.pdf
> Group 1 = 1234_test
> Group 2 = 1234
```

Step 5. '+' quantifier suddenly became lazy

```
> (.*(\d+).*)\.pdf
> Match 1 = file_1234_test.pdf
> Group 1 = file_1234_test
> Group 2 = 4
```

Of course `(.*(\d{4}).*)\.pdf` or  `(.*_(\d+).*)\.pdf` works.

```
> Match 1 = file_1234_test.pdf
> Group 1 = file_1234_test
> Group 2 = 1234
```

But then the query is (as I feel it) needless narrowing and too specific.
What if I have a list of hundreds and ...

So, Question :
Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this regex pattern: `(.*?(\d+).*)\.pdf`

It makes the first part `.*?` become lazy matching.

See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/YCSUDP/1)

Comment: To be more clear: in step 5 `+` doesn't become lazy, it is always greedy, but since `.*` (the one on the left) is evaluated first (a pattern is tested from left to right) and is greedy too, it consumes as many characters as possible. Making it lazy solve the problem.

Comment: An other possibility is to replace the dot with a character class that excludes the digits.

Comment: @Trung Problem solved, so simple, should have found it myself

Comment: @Casimir Appreciated your further clarification